# How to use ScriptControl & load Unicode res file?

Tags: delphi, vb6, code-conversion, scriptcontrol

How do I convert this VB6 code to Delphi?

```
strConv(a, vbUnicode)
```

and

```
Private cScript As New ScriptControl
cScript.Language = "Javascript"
cScript.Reset
cScript.AddCode StrConv(LoadResData(101, "RSADATA"), vbUnicode)
cScript.Run("createRsaKey", data1 , data2)
```

Comment: First of you need to decide how to execute the JavaScript in your Delphi program? What are your intentions?

Comment: Perhaps the easiest way forward would be to scrub out the JavaScript and code it all in Delphi. Don't feel that you have to translate every line of code verbatim. Feel free to choose better ways to solve problems.

Answer (score 3):

First this: I agree with @DavidHeffernan: please (pretty please) search for a way to perform the logic in Delphi.

Follow these steps:

- Find the Import Type Library menu function, depending on the Delphi version it may be under different top menu's (typically Components or Tools), or have a different name (Import ActiveX, Import COM object...)
- From the list of known type libraries, select "Microsoft Script Control", the highest version in the list (but chances are it's still just version 1.0)
- Create the wrapper unit

Then use an instance of the `TScriptControl` object, perhaps like this:

```
var
  sc:TScriptControl;
  sa:PSafeArray;
  code:WideString;
  rs:TResourceStream;
begin
  rs:=TResourceStream.Create(HInstance,'RSADATA',MakeIntResource(101));
  try
    SetLength(code,rs.Size div 2);
    rs.Read(PWideChar(code)^,rs.Size);
  finally
    rs.Free;
  end;

  sc:=TScriptControl.Create(nil);
  try
    sc.Language:='Javascript';
    sc.Reset;
    sc.AddCode(code);
    sa:=PSafeArray(TVarData(VarArrayOf([data1,data2])).VArray);
    sc.Run('createRsaKey',sa);
  finally
    sc.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: This is the answer to the question asked but one cannot help but feel that invoking remote js is not the best way to create and RSA key

Comment: It also wouldn't surprise me at all if asker did not link the js to the executable.

Comment: It says `LoadResData` so that is what `TResourceStream` does, I assume the asker knows about `.rc` and `.res` files.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: you happen to know any shorthand for that `PSafeArray(TVarData(VarArrayOf` construct? I searched for VarArrayToSafeArray but couldn't find any

Comment: No off the top of my head. Variants are not my thing.